# Should I check max and min values' rationality in bidirectional selection sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am reading an algorithm book with a part about telling bidirectional selection sort. I put its example here:

```
function selectSort2(array) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = array.length-1;
    let min = left; 
    let max = left; 
    while (left <= right) {
      min = left;
      max = left;
      for (let i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[min]) {
          min = i;
        }
        if (array[i] > array[max]) {
          max = i;
        }
      }
      swap(array, left, min);
      if (left == max) {
        max = min;
      }
      swap(array, right, max);
      left++;
      right--;
    }
}
```

And I am confused about the line `if (left == max)`. I think if the max element is at the left should be fine, and I tried to delete this block, but nothing happened to the result.

I tried to search about this and asked the copilot, but didn't get enough answers. What I know now is:

- This issue can happen when the array has duplicate elements.
- Copilot tells me if I delete this block, I might lose the max value or something, which can cause an error result.

And I think about upper info. If the rest of the array is like `[3, 3, 3, 3]`, then it will cause this issue. Max and min values will be 3, with the index being 0 in this example, but that won't cause a different result cause I swap them rather than insert them. And if the rest of the array is like `[3, 3, 3, 4]`, I think this issue won't happen. Max will be 4, and min will be 3, and they have different indexes.

So I wonder if I should check rationality about max and min values? I think the book should be correct, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Left`, `Right`, `Min` and `Max` represent indices in the array.
I suppose the `swap` function will swap the values at the indices, and won't change the indices themselves.

So when you swap `left` and `min`, the old value of left is now at the `min` position. Thus you check if `max` was pointing at `left` position, and if so, you know that this value is now at the `min` indice.

You can try to sort `[4,3,1,2]` without the check to convice yourself

Comment: I suddenly understand. I think I just drive myself confused. Thanks!